# Where should I make a api call after a success of another api call using a view model?

Tags: android, api, viewmodel, android-livedata

I'm hitting a API call and I'm getting success and I've parsed the result using retrofit and ViewModel. I'm observing the result(LiveData). Where do I hit my next API, inside the observer or after my observer?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

To chain one network call after another you could trigger the next API on the `Observer` of the first. However if the result of the first API is never used on the UI then you could sequentially hit the API on background and remove the `Observer` on the first API result.